# How to make razor not read @

Tags: html, razor

How to make razor not read @ at input pattern?

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{1,}$" title="Email must be in correct fomat" value="" placeholder="Email"   required />
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Using a double at would work: `@@`.

Alternatively you could use this [razor function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2): `@Html.Raw("@")`.